# glfwInit() freezes program

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glfw, directinput

The program gets stuck at the `glfwInit()` function. However, there are no error messages and `glfwInit()` doesn't come to a stop. It's like the main thread is sleeping or run into an infinite loop. This problem seems not to be project-specific because I tried running a program that I hadn't changed in days where the same problem occurred (this program worked also fine). I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Here is the code of my main-function which should initiate GLFW:

```cpp
int main() {

    int width, height;

    //Everything until this function will not execute and the program won't stop from its self.
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cout << "ERROR::GLFW::Could not be initialized!" << std::endl;
    }

    setUpWindow();

    GLFWwindow* window = createWindow(800, 800, "OpenGL Advanced");
    
    if (window == nullptr) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return 2;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    setUpListener(window);

    bool gladIsLoaded = loadGlad();
    if (!gladIsLoaded) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return 3;
    }

    setUpOpenGL();

    startRenderLoop(&width, &height, window);

    glfwTerminate();

    return 1;
}
```

This is the call stack:

```
ntdll.dll!NtDeviceIoControlFile()   Unknown
KernelBase.dll!DeviceIoControl()    Unknown
kernel32.dll!DeviceIoControlImplementation()    Unknown
hid.dll!00007ff86b631c2b()  Unknown
hid.dll!00007ff86b631a1b()  Unknown
dinput8.dll!00007ff83367492b()  Unknown
dinput8.dll!00007ff833674648()  Unknown
dinput8.dll!00007ff833674401()  Unknown
dinput8.dll!00007ff833671f87()  Unknown
dinput8.dll!00007ff83367424d()  Unknown
dinput8.dll!00007ff833671037()  Unknown
dinput8.dll!00007ff833678f1f()  Unknown
dinput8.dll!00007ff8336790c6()  Unknown
OpenglAdvanced.exe!_glfwInitJoysticksWin32()    C
OpenglAdvanced.exe!_glfwPlatformInit()  C
OpenglAdvanced.exe!glfwInit()   C
OpenglAdvanced.exe!main() Line 48   C++
OpenglAdvanced.exe!invoke_main() Line 79    C++
OpenglAdvanced.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() Line 288    C++
OpenglAdvanced.exe!__scrt_common_main() Line 331    C++
OpenglAdvanced.exe!mainCRTStartup() Line 17 C++
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  Unknown
```

Comment: Sounds like [this GLFW issue](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/1284)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, updating to the latest version (from 3.3.2 to 3.3.6) fixed the problem.

Comment: No, this problem is still recurring as of today. I am facing the same issue too. I face this issue after running the program many times. The only temporary solutions that I have is restarting Visual Studio or restarting your PC.